# data structuring in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have my data like, a teacher and few students with payment options.

I want to structure below data.

1. Authenticated teacher with read/write access to students profiles.
2. r/w access to Authenticated student profile.
3. invoice readable by student however, write access to teacher.

looking for inputs/help in structuring the above dB with security rules in firebase.

**Update**
Use below sample DB to test against Bradley answer.

```
 {
"invoices" : {
"stid1" : {
  "studentID" : "9EtsXHveIyaEkkLLk5hpo6vCtVx1"
}
},
"students" : {
"3d2HnQUxAbgaOqWBEqfDuhkhkj63" : {
  "name" : "s2"
},
"9EtsXHveIyaEkkLLk5hpo6vCtVx1" : {
  "name" : "s1"
}
},
 "teachers" : {
  "aiBunX1rZceD2lRslEmCrFHS2XF3" : {
  "name" : "s1"
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following database rules:

```
{

"rules": {
    // teachers profiles stored under this node
    // teachers can read and write under their own node
    "teachers": {
        "$teacherID": {
            ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $teacherID",
            ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $teacherID"
        }
    },
    // teachers can r/w student profiles, and the students can also r/w their own profile
    "students": {
        "$studentID": {
            ".read": "auth != null && (root.child('teachers').child(auth.uid).exists() || auth.uid == $studentID)",
            ".write": "auth != null && (root.child('teachers').child(auth.uid).exists() || auth.uid == $studentID)"
        }
    },
    "invoices": {
        "$invoiceID": {
            // assuming each invoice has the student ID located at /$invoiceID/studentID
            // students can read, teachers can r/w
            ".read" : "auth != null && (root.child('invoices').child($invoiceID).child('studentID').val() == auth.uid || root.child('teachers').child(auth.uid).exists())",
            ".write": "auth != null && root.child('teachers').child(auth.uid).exists()"

        }
    }
}

}
```

Works on the following database:

```
{ 

"teachers" : { 
    "aiBunX1rZceD2lRslEmCrFHS2XF3" : { 
        "name" : "s1" 
    } 
},

"students" : { 
    "3d2HnQUxAbgaOqWBEqfDuhkhkj63" : { 
        "name" : "s2" 
    }, 
    "9EtsXHveIyaEkkLLk5hpo6vCtVx1" : { 
        "name" : "s1" 
    } 
}, 

"invoice" : { 
    "stid1" : { 
        "9EtsXHveIyaEkkLLk5hpo6vCtVx1" : { 
            "ispaid" : false 
        }, 
        "studentID" : "9EtsXHveIyaEkkLLk5hpo6vCtVx1" 
    } 
} 

}
```

Comment: If node invoice is readble for students, how/who to store studentID under this node,?

Comment: @user755 only teachers can edit under this node, as you said.

Comment: @user755 i'm assuming an invoice is about a student, so it would make sense that an invoice is related to a student, via a studentID property within each invoice, or have I misunderstood?

Comment: you are right invoice is related to student. Fee paid will be updated by teacher for that particular studentid found in invoice node. i am completely new to Firebase DB, this is my first attempt to implement.

Comment: Sweet, that should work for that configuration then. Please mark answer as correct if this works!

Comment: it works, tested with simulator. to make it complete could you please add below database along with rules {
  "invoice" : {
    "stid1" : {
      "9EtsXHveIyaEkkLLk5hpo6vCtVx1" : {
        "ispaid" : false
      },
      "studentID" : "9EtsXHveIyaEkkLLk5hpo6vCtVx1"
    }
  },
  "students" : {
    "3d2HnQUxAbgaOqWBEqfDuhkhkj63" : {
      "name" : "s2"
    },
    "9EtsXHveIyaEkkLLk5hpo6vCtVx1" : {
      "name" : "s1"
    }
  },
  "teachers" : {
    "aiBunX1rZceD2lRslEmCrFHS2XF3" : {
      "name" : "s1"
    }
  }
}